# How Initializing Direct to object works in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I really don't know what question/title can explain my problem.
I'm just going to show you example.

How this works? Does compiler automatically call parameter constructor with initializer list?

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
    public:
        int k;
};
int main(){
    A obj={2};
    std::cout << obj.k; // output 2;
}
```

I was confused that compiler automatically call parameterized constructor. Then I tried to test.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
    public:
        int k;
        A(int a){   
            std::cout << "Para A" << std::endl; 
        }
};

int main(){
    A obj={2}; // error in C++98 but works in C++11 and call Para A.
    std::cout << obj.k; // Garbage value why? 
}
```

After that I think, when we didn't define constructor explicitly, then Compiler automatically assume that `A obj={firstField,SecondField,....};` mean call default constructor and then initlize fields with given values in `{....}` **So, question is that is I'm Right with this logic if not then how this works?**  `A obj={2};`

**IN C++11**

if parameterized constructor defined, then you can call that constructor by this  `A obj={values};`

Comment: @zenith sorry that was typing mistake.. Yes `obj.k` I just want to ask how` A obj={2}; `works ?

Answer (score 5):

This is called [**aggregate initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

> when we didn't define constructor explicitly, then Compiler automatically assume that `A obj={firstField,SecondField,....};` mean call default constructor and then initlize fields with given values in `{....}`

Correct.

But when you define a constructor and do `A obj = {...}` that's [**copy-list-initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: zenith can I say, compiler create implicitly initializer list in aggregate initialization?

Comment: If by "initializer list" you mean the member initializer list then no, that is not created by the compiler. The public non-static members are simply initialized from the initializers in the braced-init-list.